# Slider com 3 colunas automático sem javascript

Tags: html5, css3, slider

Estou tentando fazer um slider que tenha controle que nem esse https://codepen.io/mayurbirle/pen/eEevBZ/, porém automático e que mostre 3 imagens ao mesmo tempo

tentei implementar os controles porém não está funcionando poderiam me ajudar?

https://codepen.io/danieladuarteng/pen/oqLWQm

Comment: Com CSS vc não consegue fazer o Slide ficar Loop (a não ser que as imagens sejam um Background de um Container), O que da pra fazer com a tag imagem é todos irem para um lado só e depois retornarem pelo mesmo lado que foram. Tipo 1 2 3 vai e depos volta 3 2 1... Se quiser posso fazer um exemplo simple pra vc automático e infinito como quer...

Answer (score 1):

Segue um modelo de Slider apenas com CSS rodando de 3 em 3 images. Ele foi todo feito em Flex então está bem responsivo e fácil de entender.

Fiz a animação com @keyframes então também é bem fácil de mexe nos intervalos e na duração total da animação.

Segue o exemplo que fiz: *(clique em Executar para visualizar e em "Pagina toda" se quiser ver ampliado responsivo)*

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wraper {
    height: auto;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scroller {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    animation: slidy 6000ms infinite;
}
.wraper .scroller img {
    min-width: calc(100% / 3);
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 .5rem;
}
@keyframes slidy {
   0%{margin-left:0%;}
  20%{margin-left:0%;}

  25%{margin-left:-100%;}
  45%{margin-left:-100%;}

  50%{margin-left:-200%;}
  70%{margin-left:-200%;}

  75%{margin-left:-100%;}
  95%{margin-left:-100%;}

 100%{margin-left:0%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">

    <div class="scroller">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/220/200" alt="">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/210/200" alt="">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/230/200" alt="">
        
        <img src="http://placeskull.com/210/200" alt="">
        <img src="http://placeskull.com/220/200" alt="">
        <img src="http://placeskull.com/230/200" alt="">

        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/230/200" alt="">
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/220/200" alt="">
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/210/200" alt="">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Obrigada Hugo, mas desse jeito eu não conseguiria colocar os controles de voltar e avançar? Essa é minha dúvida, não consigo implementar esses controles aparecendo 3 imagens de uma vez

Comment: Daniela quando vc falou que queria de forma automática eu achei que vc queria rodando sozinho, sem controles. Para fazer dos dois jeitos automático e com controle ao mesmo tempo só com JS mesmo... Vc pode tentar criar um evento que manipule os slides dolicando as imagens de 3 em 3 dentro de um span por exemplo e manipular os @keyframes com JS, mas eu não entendo muito de JS e não vou saber de dizer como fazer... so a parte do css mesmo que fiz assim... as vezes isso te ajuda. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXhS6KFPLY4&t=92s